# idea out of memory when open pom.xml

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

there is intellij-idea log for the action of open pom.xml in idea(when open pom.xml in idea,the committed memory reached the maximum heap ):

```
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.resize(HashMap.java:699)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.putVal(HashMap.java:624)
at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:607)
at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:220)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.addToCache(MavenIndex.java:540)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.lambda$addArtifact$2(MavenIndex.java:526)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex$$Lambda$4685/0x0000000103075040.doTask(Unknown Source)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.doIndexTask(MavenIndex.java:628)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndex.addArtifact(MavenIndex.java:515)
at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.indices.MavenIndicesManager$IndexFixer$AddToIndexRunnable.run(MavenIndicesManager.java:489)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.Update$1.run(Update.java:108)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:333)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:323)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:273)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$$Lambda$1670/0x0000000101855c40.run(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:287)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:242)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:369)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:355)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:220)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:216)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$200(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:27)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.execute(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:195)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1$$Lambda$511/0x00000001006bfc40.run(Unknown Source)
at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:213)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:184)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)`
```

Comment: Just increase the heap: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html to 1-2GB depending on project size

Comment: If it does not help, share logs folder to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Which IDEA version do you use?